# How to convert Source[String, Future[IOResult]] to Source[ByteString, Future[IOResult]]

Tags: playframework, akka-stream

Need to convert

```
val graph: Source[String, Future[IOResult]]= <some flow>
```

to

```
val graph: Source[ByteString, Future[IOResult]] =<some flow>
```

so that it can be pass to Result as shown below:

```
Result(
        header = ResponseHeader(OK, Map(CONTENT_DISPOSITION → s"application")),
        body = HttpEntity.Streamed(graph, None, None)
        )
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [map](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/stream/scaladsl/Source.html#map[T](f:Out=%3ET):FlowOps.this.Repr[T]) method on a `Source` and that `Repr[T]` is an an alias for a `Source[T, Mat]` with the same materializer.

So you can make a `Source[String, Mat]` into a `Source[ByteString, Mat]` with:

```
graph.map(ByteString(_))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `via` to transform the elements of your existing source:

```scala
val byteStringSource: Source[ByteString, Future[IOResult]] =
  graph.via(Flow.fromFunction(ByteString(_)))
```